# nginx rewrite regex min,max repetition

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I am using this rewrite in NGINX. 
`rewrite ^/test[^a-zA-Z0-9]{2}/?$ https://www.google.com permanent; // doesn't work`

The server fails to start with I add the `min {2}` repetition in the regex. The server comes up when I remove that like here: 
 `rewrite ^/test[^a-zA-Z0-9]/?$ https://www.google.com permanent; // this works`

I have tried both `{min,max}` params.
The error that I get when I use the `min` repetition is as below. 
`directive "rewrite" is not terminated by ";"`

The context of this rewrite is `server`.

Can someone tell if what am I missing? Is there some module that need to be installed for this to work?
My prod NGINX version is 1.4 and I tried it on my local with 1.10.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is by design -- curly brackets are special in nginx.conf, if used as a part of a regular expression, then you have to use double quotes around your regular expression if you're using the braces.

http://nginx.org/r/rewrite

> If a regular expression includes the “}” or “;” characters, the whole expressions should be enclosed in single or double quotes.

E.g.,

```
 rewrite "^/test[^a-zA-Z0-9]{2}/?$" https://www.google.com/ permanent;
```

Comment: Ahh. thanks. I knew it was something trivial. Will accept in 5 mins.